# Multiple search and replace actions in one large text file

Tags: linux, vim, sed, find-and-replace

I have a big text file (about 2GB). I want to do five search and replace actions on the same file, and would like to do this in one command. Normally I use vim, open the file, do one replace action, then the next, etc. There is one catch, as I noticed that after three or four searches vim crashes because of memory issues.

Here are two examples of the command I use in Vim:

```
:%s/www\.abcdef/www.test.abcdef/g 
:%s/www\.klmnop/www.test.klmnop/g
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use sed like this :

```
sed -i "s/www\.abcdef/www.test.abcdef/g;s/www\.kmlnop/www.test.klmnop/g;" yourfile.txt
```

`-i` option stands for "in place" replacement. You can tell sed to create a backup of your file providing an extension to this option ( `-i.bak` will backup yourfile.txt as yourfile.txt.bak ).

Comment: That's quick! Not only your answer ;-) but this script with 5 search and replaces is about 10x faster as just opening the file in vim. One thing confused me though. At first I thought the .bak file would be the edited file, but it's the original of course.

Comment: Ten search and replace actions (with thousands of hits) in a 2GB file in one go, no memory problems. Less than two minutes on an average desktop - super!

Comment: One question... You escape the dots in the replace string. Is this necessary?

Comment: You're welcome @rxt :) Actually, you're right, you can use non-escaped dots in the replacement string in `sed`. I tried, and it works. There's a good thread in [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script), and the accepted answer not mention dots as characters to escape.

Comment: @rxt you said _replace_ string, sorry, no you don't need to escape them there.

Answer (score 6):

If you have many more search patterns, you could save them in a file and read the substitutions from there. For example, say these are the contents of `replacements.txt`:

```
www\.abcdef www.test.abcdef 
www\.klmnop www.test.klmnop
```

You can then read a list of N replacements and replace them with this:

```
while read from to; do
  sed -i "s/$from/$to/" infile.txt ; 
done < replacements.txt
```

NOTES:

- This assumes your search strings do not contain spaces and any strange characters need to be escaped in `replacements.txt`.
- It will run one `sed` per replacement which may take a while if you have many replacement operations.
- It can deal with an arbitrary number of replacements (thousands or millions or whatever) as long as you don't mind that it will take a bit more time.

Another option would be to write the above as a `sed` script:

```
s/www\.abcdef/www\.test\.abcdef/g;
s/www\.kmlnop/www\.test\.klmnop/g;
s/aaaa/bbbb/g;
s/cccc/dddd/g;
s/eeee/ffff/g;
```

You can then run the script on your file and it will make all the replacements in one go:

```
sed -f replace.sed infile.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the ,,other option''. Could be handy to have the replacements stored in a file! (I hope I'll remember that...)

Comment: +1 for the "other option" also because it uses native functionality rather than a custom script, so is more portable/shareable

Comment: @DavidCook thanks, but it is no more native or portable than the other. The first approach is using a POSIX shell loop, it is exactly as portable as the second. It will just be much slower since it uses a shell loop.

Comment: You're right, what I meant is that the sed script file format is more portable, because it uses builtin sed functionality rather than a script, which would have to be shared alongside the replacements.txt file.
Nevertheless, they are both great options!