# replacing 6000+ strings in >2GB text file

Tags: bash, sed

I'd like to search and replace more than 6000 strings in a > 2GB text file.

```
sed -i "s/search/replace/g" 2gbfile.log
```

is taking forever. Especially if you have to do it 6000+ times.

So I came up with a script that splits the 2 GB file into chunks so that I can parallelize the effort. I'm running 48 processes simultaneously (64 cores available), but still, it's taking rather long.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "sorting..."
sort bigbigbigfile | awk -F, '{print $2,$1,$3}' > bigbigbigfile.work

CPUS=$(( $(lscpu |grep "On-line CPU(s) list"|grep -Eo '0-[0-9]+'|cut -f2 -d-) + 1))
CPUSUSABLE=$(echo "$CPUS*0.75" | bc | cut -f1 -d.)
NUMLINES=$(cat all-temperatures.sort | wc -l)
SPLIT=$(echo "$NUMLINES / $CPUSUSABLE" | bc | cut -f1 -d.)
echo "cutting..."
split -l $SPLIT bigbigbigfile.work chunkstoworkwith

mapfile -t REPLACEME < replace.list

echo "seding..."
for chunk in $(ls chunkstoworkwith*); do
        (
        for i in "${!REPLACEME[@]}"; do
                counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
                sed -i "s/ ${REPLACEME[$i]} / $counter /g" $chunk
        done
        ) &
done
```

This works. But I think it could be even faster when I search and replace in memory, rather than having sed replacing in-place and doing 6000+ replaces in 48 files. This sums up to almost 300k sed calls, which results in a lot of file opening/closing/writing/whatever.

Any idea on how to speed this up and do the replacements in memory and flushing out the data after everything has been changed?

Comment: HI HansPeter. Welcome to SuperUser. This question would seem to be better answered at StackOverflow, rather than SuperUser, as it involves Bash script. have you asked this question there?

Comment: [Multiple search and replace actions in one large text file](https://superuser.com/q/618407/241386), [Replacing multiple strings in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51608196/995714), [Replace text quickly in very large file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255373/44425), [Replace Multiple Strings in a Large Text File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41192945/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is parsing the entire chunk for every single replacement!

Meaning that for every chunk, the script opens, goes through all lines, possibly perform 1 replacement, closes the file and moves it the original file (due to the `-i` option).

Provided you want to replace the pattern with a counting number, here is a way to perform all replacements at once for every chunks:

```
sed -f <(awk '{print "s/ "$1" / "++c" /"}' replace.list) -i "$chunk"
```

The `-f` option allows to take a sed script as input and will be executed at once for all lines of the `$chunk` file.

This will likely reduce the overall timing...

Comment: Agreed. First improvement is to do all the replacements  in one file access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why your sed is going so slow, you would probably have to debug or watch it closer to really find out, but if it is trying to write 6,000 times and that's slowing it down, you could skip the `-i` and just have sed write the whole (changed) file out once:

```
sed "s/search/replace/g" 2gbfile.log > 2bgfile-AfterSed.log
```

Comment: This would also require 6000 sed calls (for each pattern that needs a replace), and it cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Sed's only running once, reading once and writing once, and I'm guessing it could be the in-place writing that's so slow. How long does this method take?

Comment: `$ time sed "s/search/replace/g" 2gbfile.log > 2bgfile-AfterSed.log

#real    0m18.451s`

Comment: (18*6000)/3600 = 30 hours.

Comment: That's only on 1/6000th of the 2gb file. Anyway without knowing where the bottleneck is we're basically just guessing, usually reads & writes are a lot slower than any computations like a basic find/replace

Comment: probably piping the result to the next sed would be faster than saving the intermediate result to a file. However I think that this needs a specialized solution since no general tools are for replacing such a huge amount of strings in a big file